# Unity Firebase Google Sign In

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, authentication, google-signin

Google Sign in always throwing Goolge Sign In Exception.

I'm using:
a. Unity 2018.1.5f1
b. firebase_unity_sdk_6.2.0
c. google-signin-plugin-1.0.4

Steps: 
1. Setup a Unity App on Firebase.

2. Imported both the plugin along with Sample Google Script.
3. I'm using Google Sample's Sign In script.
4. Added a SHA-1 fingerprint from C:\Users\user.android\debug.keystore, to Firebase console.
5. Downloaded and added googleservices.json to root of the Assets folder.
6. Used the id from oauth client type 3 to the webclient ID.
7. Always getting Google Sign In Exception

NOTE: No third part modules added, just Unity Ads.

```
void Awake() {
      configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration {
            WebClientId = webClientId,//using id  from google_services.json
            RequestIdToken = true
      };
 }

public void OnSignIn() {
      GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
      GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
      GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
      AddStatusText("Calling SignIn");

      GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(
        OnAuthenticationFinished, 
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Its an Android build.

If anyone can help, will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable Google Sign In in the Firebase console (under Authentication/Sign-in method)? You have to enable each authentication method separately (email, google, phone, etc.). Not sure what exactly you mean here: `Used the id from oauth client type 3 to the webclient ID.`

Comment: Yes i have enabled that from firebase.
It meant: 
I have added client_id from google_services.json to the webclient_id in request to signin.

Comment: Well finally solved it after 2 days of struggle!

Solution: Do make sure in the "OAuth consent screen" in google api console you've added name of your application properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you did everything you saw on here and on other pages but nothing worked yet, check the SHA-1 that you use on Firebase Console.

As you know there are 2 SHA certificates on Google Play Console and as I see, most of the time that confuses people.

You need to use App Signing Certificates before you upload your App to Google Play Console.

Upload Certificates are for testing on emulator etc. without uploading to Google Play Console.

Here is the screenshot that you can see the details
[image]

And also do not forget that Web SDK configuration must be Web client (Auto-created for Google Sign-in) which you can see on the Google cloud platform.